# How to print two hyphens together using lowdown?

Tags: markdown

Colleagues, tell me how to display two hyphens together using Markdown (specifically, I am using [lowdown](https://kristaps.bsd.lv/lowdown/))?

I need to write the line "--help, -h" with emphasis. I write the following line:

```
**--help**, **-h**
```

as a result I get

> **-help**, **-h**

Why does lowdown bite off one hyphen?

Comment: It looks like that's the lowdown for an [en-dash](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/man5/lowdown.5.html). Maybe try either escaping them with \, or using backticks to mark the switch as code?

Comment: I already tried \--, -\-, \-\-. No result.

Comment: The method with \*\*\`--\`help\*\* turned out. But somehow this is not right at all. Isn't there an easier way.

Comment: What's not right about it? I would have backticked the whole thing: \*\*\`--help\`**. After all, it _is_ a (short) code snippet. At any rate, I don't know of an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not standard Markdown behaviour.

lowdown [advertises among its features](https://kristaps.bsd.lv/lowdown/#input) something called "smart typography", which appears to be the culprit. The source file `lowdown/smartypants.c` shows a mapping [from `--`](https://github.com/kristapsdz/lowdown/blob/edca6ce6d5336efb147321a43c47a698de41bb7c/smartypants.c#L101) to the [HTML entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) [`&ndash;`](https://github.com/kristapsdz/lowdown/blob/edca6ce6d5336efb147321a43c47a698de41bb7c/smartypants.c#L75).

I don't see any way to change this behaviour for a single "smart" mapping, but you can [disable it entirely](https://kristaps.bsd.lv/lowdown/lowdown.1.html#out-no-smarty) by running with the `--out-no-smarty` argument:

> Do not use the smart typography filter. By default, certain character sequences are translated into output-specific glyphs.

If you want to get more granular than that, you may have to modify the source and build your own binary.